# Getting last_value MariaDB SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have this data in the table:

| internal_id | match_id | company_id | market_id | selection_id | odds_value | update_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1442 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 2021-01-04 18:58:19 |
| 1 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 2021-01-04 18:57:19 |
| 2 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 2 | 19 | 2021-01-04 18:57:19 |
| 3 | 8483075 | 66 | 1 | 3 | 1.08 | 2021-01-04 18:57:19 |

I'm trying to get last value of odds_value from whole table for each combination of match_id + company_id + market_id + selection_id based on update_date.

I wrote this query which is not working:

```
SELECT
    odds.`internal_id`,
    odds.`match_id`,
    odds.`company_id`,
    odds.`market_id`,
    odds.`selection_id`,
    odds.`update_date`,
    odds.`odd_value`,
    LAST_VALUE (odds.`odd_value`) OVER (PARTITION BY odds.`internal_id`, odds.`match_id`, odds.`company_id`, odds.`market_id`, odds.`selection_id` ORDER BY odds.`update_date` DESC) AS last_value
FROM
    `odds`
LEFT JOIN `matches` ON matches.match_id = odds.match_id
WHERE
    odds.match_id = 8483075
    and odds.company_id = 66
GROUP BY
    odds.match_id,
    odds.company_id,
    odds.market_id,
    odds.selection_id
```

For match_id=8483075 & market_id=1 and selection_id=1 I'm getting odd_value 10 instead of 100.
What am I doing wrong? or maybe there is a better way to get that (using internal_id = higher means most recent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LAST_VALUE()` is very strange.  The problem is that the default window frame for the ordering is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

I won't go into the details, but the fix is to just always use `FIRST_VALUE()`.  I'm also fixing the `PARTITION BY` to match the description in your question:

```
FIRST_VALUE(odds.odd_value) OVER (PARTITION BY odds.company_id, odds.market_id, odds.selection_id
                                  ORDER BY odds.update_date DESC
                                 ) AS last_value
```

Ironically, you already have a descending sort, so your last value was really fetching the first value anyway, sort of.

Comment: I'm really confused with this one. Seems so easy but nothing seems to work.
Your fix shows me exactlly the same results. I also played with all combinations of FIRST_VALUE/LAST_VALUE and ASC/DESC order for odds.update_date and I'm always getting the same results. Is it normal?

Comment: @UrukMorg . . . Your `partition by` is then at fault.  I adjusted it to be what you describe in the text rather than what you have in your query,

Comment: From next tests I figure out that the problem was with Group BY at the ned of query.
I used your FIRST_VALUE approach. Thx a lot.